# Scala grammar for Antlr4 is not working

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm using the grammar on the Antlr github page: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/scala

But the grammar has a problem based on reading the reported issue on GitHub.

Here is my code:

```
 InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
 System.out.println(targetStream.toString());
 ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(targetStream);
 ScalaLexer lexer = new ScalaLexer(input);    
 CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
 ...
```

The error message is:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'object HelloWorld {'
```

I searched the issue, several other people also found the problem. It is hard to understand why such a state-of-the-art tool has such an obvious issue, but the issue is there. I'm not an export of parsing and just need a working scala parser in Java. Are there any other grammar I can use for scala? Or are there any other scala parser written in Java?

Comment: The grammars posted there are user contributions. They are not part of ANTLR.

Comment: Welcome to open source.   If it doesn't work, its your problem to fix it.

Comment: This is a pronouncement that you found an error in community contributed code, then a request for another off-site resource.  Off-topic.  Fix it yourself, or find your own alternative, but this is not topical question.